# Number of permutations in a list, including permutations of subsets of that list?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[1, 2, 3] has 6 permutations, i.e. 3!

[1, 2] has 2 permutations, i.e. 2!.

But, how do I compute the number of possible permutations in a list, given that I can arbitrarily remove any number of elements?

For example, [1, 2] would have [1], [2], [2,1], [1,2], []. So 5.

Comment: Just to clarify: can the list have duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

*The following analysis assumes the list contains no duplicate elements*. Given a set of size $n$, each subset has size between $0$ and $n$. Given a size $0 \leq k \leq n$, there are precisely $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$. Each subset of size $k$ has $k!$ permutations, so the total number of possible permutations of subsets is $$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}k! = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}.$$

**Edit**: If the list can contain duplicates, the analysis is not as clean. Suppose it has $n$ total elements, with $m$ distinct elements (where $1 \leq m \leq n$). Then, we can treat it as a multiset $S$, and let the set of $m$ distinct elements be $T$. The multiset can be represented as a function $\alpha : T \to \mathbb{Z}_+$, where for an element $t \in T$, $\alpha(t)$ states how many times $t$ appears in $S$. For example, if $S = \{a,a,b,c,b,b\}$, then $\alpha(c) = 1$, $\alpha(a) = 2$, and $\alpha(b) = 3$.

The number of permutations of a multisubset of $S$ can be computed using the [formula for permutations with repetition](https://brilliant.org/wiki/permutations-with-repetition/). In our notation, if $U$ is a multisubset of $S$ represented by $\beta: T \to \mathbb{Z_+}$ where $\beta(t) \leq \alpha(t)$ for all $t \in T$, then the number of permutations of $U$ is $$\frac{|U|!}{\prod_{u \in U}\beta(u)!}.$$ The total number of permutations is then the summation of this quantity over all possible multisubsets $U'$ of $S$. Note that there are $\prod_{t \in T} (1 + \alpha(t))$ distinct multisubsets in total.

Comment: I see your argument, but I have one problem. (Sorry accidentally posted too early).

Basically, [1,2,3] and [2,3,4] both have the subset [3]. So, your answer doesn't take into account duplicates/collisions? Edit: actually, let me think about it, I might be wrong. I suck at math sorry.

Comment: See the new edit, I have added a bit of analysis for the case of duplicate elements.

Comment: I think it's interesting to note that your formula can be written $n! \sum_{k=0}^n 1/k! \approx e \cdot n!$ for $n$ large.